# Is this a "correct" approach to multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to understand multiprocessing in Python. I've made a simple task to try this, generate a number of random tan(a) values and put them in a list. I just need some validation on my progress, is the code example a "correct" way of doing this task? Is there a better way in Python?

```
from typing import List
from math import sin, cos, sqrt
from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool
import random
import time

JOBS = int(1e8)
BATCHES: int = 10

def verify_result(result: List[int]) -> bool:
    if len(result) < JOBS:
        print(f"Too few results! ({len(result)}/{JOBS})")
        return False
    for r in result:
        if not isinstance(r, float):
            print(f"Wrong type for result element ({type(r)} != float)")
            return False
    return True

def calculate(_=None) -> float:
    a: float = sqrt( random.uniform(0, 1000) )
    return sin(a) / cos(a)

def sequential(n: int) -> List[float]:
    return [ calculate() for _ in range(n) ]

def concurrent(n: int) -> List[float]:
    pool = ThreadPool(BATCHES)
    result = [ None for _ in range(JOBS) ]
    result = list(pool.map(calculate, result))
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python Runtimes:")
    
    # Concurrent timed
    start = time.time()
    res = concurrent(JOBS)
    duration = time.time() - start
    print(f"Concurrent: {duration} s (STATUS: {'Success' if verify_result(res) else 'Failure'})")
    
    # sequential timed
    start = time.time()
    res = sequential(JOBS)
    duration = time.time() - start
    print(f"Sequential: {duration} s (STATUS: {'Success' if verify_result(res) else 'Failure'})")
```

Comment: Just a couple of observations: (1) Don't name `multiprocessing.Pool` a `ThreadPool` (threads are not processes). (2) Use `time.perf_counter` for timing, not `time.time`. (3) Dividing by `cos(a)` might be a division by 0. (4) Make your `result` list (strange name) a generator expression by using `()` instead of `[]`. (5) Better use the pool as a context manager (`with ...`). (6) You don't have to make the return of `Pool.map` into a list - it is already one. But I think overall you're on a good track :)

Comment: Thank you @Timus! That is just the kind of feedback I was hoping for! I’ll look into it!